# Run-Time Configuring a Hibernate Validation Annotation

Tags: bean-validation

I have some business validation logic of the form "X is valid IFF Service Y returns Z", where X and Z are known at compile time, and Y's location is loaded from a Spring configuration file.

I'd like to use JSR-303 annotation-based validation, together with the Spring config, so I can write code like the following:

Custom class level constraint annotation:

```
@MyValidation
public class X { .... }
```

ConstraintValidator for *@MyValidation*:

```
public class MyValidationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidation, X> {
   private MyService service;
   public MyService getService() { return service; }
   public void setService(MyService serv) { this.service = serv; }
   //Validation Logic...
}
```

Spring config:

```
<bean id="ServiceY" class="...">
   ...
</bean>
<bean id="mvv" class="MyValidationValidator">
   <property name="service" value="ServiceY" />
</bean>
```

But my attempts at combining these in that fashion are failing, as the validator's property is not getting set.

Right now, I'm using Spring AOP Interceptors as a workaround, but that's not ideal in my mind.

One of the other questions here, made me think of using a properties file/property, but wouldn't that require me to repeat the service's configuration?

Another mentioned defining the constraint mapping programmatically, but if I'm doing that, I'm probably better-off with my workaround.

Any clues on how to do that dynamic configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to set up a Bean Validation validator:

```
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

A validator set up that way will internally use a `ConstraintValidatorFactory`implementation that performs dependency injection on the created validator instances, just mark the `service` field in your validator with `@Inject` or `@Autowired`. Note that it's not required to set up the constraint validator itself as Spring bean.

You can find more details in the Spring [reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview).